# I want to remove duplicate Object using javascript/jquery. is it possible easily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

I have created one array of object, and I want to insert Unique objects.
    var a=[];

```
a.push(new Number(11));
a.push({aa:"asdf",bb:"sadf"}
a.push({aa:"asdf",bb:"sadf"}

JSON.stringify(a)
"[11,{"aa":"asdf","bb":"sadf"},{"aa":"asdf","bb":"sadf"}]"
```

I want result like

```
JSON.stringify(a)
"[11,{"aa":"asdf","bb":"sadf"}]"
```

Comment: For reference :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

`var uniqueArray=[]` is your `resultArray`. `Array.indexOf` is used to find whether the element already exist in the `uniqueArray`, if not simply push to `uniqueArray`, otherwise its a duplicate no need to push, resultant will be `uniqueArray`:

```
var uniqueArray=[];  //result array of contains duplicate free elements
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  //to check for duplication in the result array
   if(uniqueArray.indexOf(a[i])<0)
      uniqueArray.push(a[i]);
}

return uniqueArray;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code, so the OP can understand it.

Comment: var uniqueArray=[]; is your resultArray. Array.indexOf is used to find whether the element already exist in the uniqueArray, if not simply push to uniqueArray, otherwise its a duplicate no need to push, resultant will be uniqueArray @beerwin